# Python frames- List Box

Tags: wxpython

THe below code creates a frame with a list box to drag and drop. 
I would like to understand the code in the below line..

FileAndTextDropTarget is a class..This class is called with 2 functions--OnFileDrop & OnTextDrop..My question is how OnFileDrop or OnTextDrop is called without the parameter files or text being passed..

self.dt = FileAndTextDropTarget(self.OnFileDrop,
                                        self.OnTextDrop)

**Code:**

```
class DropTargetFrame(wx.Frame):
    pdb.set_trace()
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", 
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize,
                 style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
                 name="DropTargetFrame"):
        super(DropTargetFrame, self).__init__(parent, id,
                                              title, pos,
                                              size, style,
                                              name)

        # Attributes
        choices = ["Drag and Drop Text or Files here",]
        self.list = wx.ListBox(self, 
                               choices=choices)
        self.dt = FileAndTextDropTarget(self.OnFileDrop,
                                        self.OnTextDrop)

        self.list.SetDropTarget(self.dt)

        # Setup
        self.CreateStatusBar()

    def OnFileDrop(self, files):
        self.PushStatusText("Files Dropped")
        for f in files:
            self.list.Append(f)

    def OnTextDrop(self, text):
        self.PushStatusText("Text Dropped")
        self.list.Append(text)


class FileAndTextDropTarget(wx.PyDropTarget):
    """Drop target capable of accepting dropped files and text"""
    def __init__(self, file_callback, text_callback):
        assert callable(file_callback)
        assert callable(text_callback)
        super(FileAndTextDropTarget, self).__init__()

        # Attributes
        self.fcallback = file_callback # Drop File Callback
        self.tcallback = text_callback # Drop Text Callback
        self._data = None
        self.txtdo = None
        self.filedo = None

        # Setup
        self.InitObjects()

    def InitObjects(self):
        """Initializes the text and file data objects"""
        self._data = wx.DataObjectComposite()
        self.txtdo = wx.TextDataObject()
        self.filedo = wx.FileDataObject()
        self._data.Add(self.txtdo, False)
        self._data.Add(self.filedo, True)
        self.SetDataObject(self._data)

    def OnData(self, x_cord, y_cord, drag_result):
        """Called by the framework when data is dropped on the target"""
        if self.GetData():
            data_format = self._data.GetReceivedFormat()
            if data_format.GetType() == wx.DF_FILENAME:
                self.fcallback(self.filedo.GetFilenames())
            else:
                self.tcallback(self.txtdo.GetText())

        return drag_result
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, when you call "SetDropTarget", you tell wxPython to watch for mouse events over that part of your GUI. The TextDataObject and similar contain the "smarts" to know what formats it supports and how to render it when it gets there (per the wxPython demo).

So when you select something and start dragging it, wxPython can tell. See also:

- http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.DropTarget.html
- http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.DataObject.html